# After a while loop: Why is an array that was just written to empty?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop

We're currently trying to implement the kmeans algorithm in java. Our problem is this:

We're using the `getData()` method to fill a two dimensional array with data from a file. Inside the while loop in the `getData()` method we have a `println()` and we have another one right before the return command.

The first `println()` gives us the correct values we've just gotten from the file.

The second `println()` just gives us `0.0` for every field inside that array, except for `arrayList[299][0]`.

Why is that?

```
class KMeans {

    // Number of clusters
    int numberOfClusters = 4;
    // Starting point for each cluster (these values should be better than completely random values for our given data set)
    static double[] a = new double[]{-1.5, 2.0};
    static double[] b = new double[]{-1.5, 7.0};
    static double[] c = new double[]{1.5, 7.0};
    static double[] d = new double[]{1.5, 2.0};
    static double[][] pointArray;

    // This calculates the distance between a given point from the data set and a centroid
    public static double calculateDistance(double[] point, double[] centroid) {
        // get difference for X coordinates
        double maxX = Math.max(point[0], centroid[0]);
        double minX = Math.min(point[0], centroid[0]);
        double differenceX = maxX - minX;
        double differenceXSquared = Math.pow(differenceX, 2);

        // get difference for Y coordinates
        double maxY = Math.max(point[1], centroid[1]);
        double minY = Math.min(point[1], centroid[1]);
        double differenceY = maxY - minY;
        double differenceYSquared = Math.pow(differenceY, 2);

        // The whole thing is nothing other than pythagoras
        double zSquared = differenceXSquared + differenceYSquared;
        double z = Math.sqrt(zSquared);
        return z;
    }

    // This calculates which of the given distances is the lowest
    public static double[] nearestCluster(double e, double f, double g, double h) {
        double x = Math.min(e, f);
        double y = Math.min(x, g);
        double z = Math.min(y, h);

        if (z == e) {
            return a;
        }
        if (z == f) {
            return b;
        }
        if (z == g) {
            return c;
        } else {
            return d;
        }
    }

    // Read the file 
    public static double[][] getData() {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/john/Downloads/data.txt"))) {
            String line;
            int i = 1;
            int j = 0;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // Create the array in which we store each value
                pointArray = new double[i][4];
                //Splits each line a the space and writes it to an array
                String[] split = line.split("\\s+");

                // Cast the strings to double and write them to our pointArray         
                pointArray[j][0] = Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
                pointArray[j][1] = Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
                System.out.println(pointArray[0][0]);
                i++;
                j++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        System.out.println(pointArray[0][0]);        
        return pointArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        pointArray = getData();
        for (double[] x : pointArray) {
            double distanceA = calculateDistance(x, a);
            double distanceB = calculateDistance(x, b);
            double distanceC = calculateDistance(x, c);
            double distanceD = calculateDistance(x, d);

            // Assigns the closest cluster to each point (not too efficent because we call the function twice, but it works)
            x[2] = nearestCluster(distanceA, distanceB, distanceC, distanceD)[0];
            x[3] = nearestCluster(distanceA, distanceB, distanceC, distanceD)[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `pointArray = new double[i][4];` - what are you trying to do here? You reset the array variable in each iteration.

Comment: The idea is to dynamically scale the size of the array depending on the size of the data we get from the file.

Comment: That doesn't work that way. Better use a List.

Comment: That doesn't work like that, arrays cannot be rescaled, only new arrays can be made and then the old data copied into it. The API has classes that do this, like ```ArrayList```.

Comment: Moreover, you are always printing `pointArray[0][0]` and not `pointArray[j][i]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
pointArray = new double[i][4];
```

reinitializes the array each time through the loop. In effect you're throwing away every value except the last line that you read.

Instead, use an `ArrayList` to hold each individual line. Set it up before the `while` loop like this:

```
List<Double[]> pointList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can add to it at each line like this:

```
Double[] points = new Double[4];
// ...
points[0] = Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
// etc.
pointList.add(points);
```

Then either return `pointList` or convert it to an array for return.